# How I do open Rstudio properly?

Tags: runtime-error, rstudio

When I start the Rstudio (windows) the follow error message is showed:

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.12.1+402 "Ocean Storm " (4da58325, 2024-01-28) for windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.12.1+402 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 3221225477.

Error output:

```
[No errors emitted]
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*C:/Users/ronan/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-ronan.log*

```
2024-03-18T16:38:46.002050Z [rsession-ronan] ERROR system error 5 (Acesso negado); OCCURRED AT auto __cdecl rstudio::core::system::ChildProcess::terminate::<lambda_0837bcc20cbf20264fbd4fbbbf2e36d5>::operator ()(void) const src/cpp/core/system/Win32ChildProcess.cpp:294; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::core::system::ProcessSupervisor::terminateAll(void) src/cpp/core/system/Process.cpp:379
2024-03-18T16:38:47.013791Z [rsession-ronan] WARNING Process supervisor did not terminate within 1 second; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl `anonymous-namespace'::rCleanup(bool) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-ocean-storm\src\cpp\session\SessionMain.cpp:1338
2024-03-18T16:38:47.013791Z [rsession-ronan] WARNING Process supervisor did not terminate within 1 second; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl `anonymous-namespace'::rCleanup(bool) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-ocean-storm\src\cpp\session\SessionMain.cpp:1338
```

The problem started suddenly when I tried to read a small excel file.
I already had install and uninstall R and Rstudio twice.
I tried to execute the Rstudio as administrator.
I tried to follow the instructions
However, despite R is working well Rstudio does not work.